# VSTS Release Pipeline Gate Success Criteria for HTTPS Status 200

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to use the VSTS release pipeline Gate feature to test a new Azure Function after it's deployed.
I have tried the 'Invoke Azure Function' and 'Invoke REST API' deployment gates, but can't get them to succeed.

I would like to just call the endpoint and for the gate to succeed if it receives a simple HTTP 200 or 202 response.

Latest effort was to put this in the 'Success criteria' field

```
eq(count(jsonpath('$.responses[?(@.httpStatusCode != 200)]')), 1)
```

The Processing Gate step just says 'No samples have yet arrived' and there are no logs.

Has anyone successfully done this? Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe related https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=vsts#configure-gate

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman, I have been through all the docs and I can't find any usefule examples of Success ctieria...as usual!!

Comment: Does the response from your Azure Function include the http status code? Can you share a response sample?

Comment: There are some docs over here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/servertaskauthoring.md

Answer (score 3):

Just faced the same problem for the "Invoke Azure function" task and it is so, that if you simply need to check whether it's `200` or not you don't specify the "Success criteria" at all, it works out of the box. I hope it's the same with the `202`.

[image: like this]

It's kinda mentioned in [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/azure-function?view=azure-devops), but as usual you should read between the lines or something.

> **Completion Event** - How the task reports completion. Can be API response (the default) - completion is **when function returns
>   success** and **success criteria evaluates to true**, or Callback -
>   the Azure function makes a callback to update the timeline record.
>
> **Success criteria** - How to parse the **response body** for success.